# JetBrains One Dark Theme Demo page uses this font. What is it called?

Tags: fonts, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, monospace

can someone please help me identify this monospace font? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Operator Mono ScreenSmart](https://www.typography.com/fonts/operator/styles/operatormonoscreensmart) + [Operator Mono Ligatures](https://github.com/kiliman/operator-mono-lig) for ligatures.